# How to merge row of data and count sum of value in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

1) I want to do like this !! (merge Date like a column 3 and count values each Date like a column 4) [image: I want to do like this !!]
              .2)This is my result. I want to merge ex. Dec 1 and count all of Dec 1 like picture 1

[image: This is my result. I want to merge ex. Dec 1 and count all of Dec 1 like picture 1]

3) this is my pivot setting 
(1.Group by attribute = CustomerID) 
(2.Column groupping attributes = Country)[image]

Answer (score 1):

the right approach depends on your final goal.
In your case removing the time portion from the date would probably be sufficient.

Put the Operator "Generate Attributes" right before the Aggregation/Pivoting with the following settings:

attribute name: InvoiceDate

function expressions: date_parse_custom(date_str_custom(InvoiceDate,"yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyy-MM-yy")

Regards,
Edin